# If I bought Destiny on my Canadian Account, can I play it with my US account?

Tags: ps4, destiny

I want to buy Destiny with my Canadian account (I don't have PlayStation Plus with this one), but my primary account and the one I play the most is US. Will I be able to play without restrictions? Of course, both of the accounts are on the same PS4, but [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-4-Support/Destiny-on-sub-account-PS4/td-p/44475648) I read about some problems other people are having with this.

I know that Destiny allows you to play play the game with multiple accounts, what I want to know is whether or not I can play the game through both accounts if I buy it with an account that does not have an active PlayStation Plus membership (my Canadian account).

Comment: That´s different, bro. I know that games aren´t region locked. I ask specifically about Destiny, since I read there are some problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**:
Yes, you can.

**Longer answer**:
From my personal experience. I have two accounts on PS4 - US with PS Plus and European without PS Plus. I bought the game digitally on US account almost on launch and played ever since on EU account (for historical reasons, most of my trophies are there).

You will be able to play normally, but you will miss out on profile-specific exlusive items. For example, before The Dark Below everyone with pre-order got exclusive Sparrow. To use pre-order items like that you'll need to play on account that bougth the game.

Answer (score 2):

PlayStation Games are not region locked, only the stores are region locked. I bought games from the UK PSN store with an alternate account, but I can still play them on my EU NL account. I also bought the Last of Us for PS4 during my visit in Iraq. I still can play that on my Dutch PSN account.

TL;dr: Yes, you should be able to play Destiny on your US account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play from whichever account you desire.

However you need to keep future DLC purchases consistent to that original account where you bought the game from.